getting count of elements in the API response before making the call?
I want to check if there is any way to know the number of elements that would be returned by the response of a GET request call from Postman before making the actual call?
I tried to search for a way but didn't got any solutions. Kindly help.

You can't get an item count of a response array before a request call.
But you can get a count before main request at Pre-test Script.

In Pre-requst Script tab
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'your URL for getting count',
    method: 'GET',
    header: 'Content-Type: application/json'
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        pm.test("Status code is 200", () => {
            pm.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        });
        const responseJson = res.json();
        console.log(responseJson.length);
        pm.environment.set("ItemCount", responseJson.length);
    }
});

Demo
I will count of array
GET https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals

The item count is 50.

Main request URL
GET https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1

Pre-request Script tab
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals',
    method: 'GET',
    header: 'Content-Type: application/json'
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        pm.test("Status code is 200", () => {
            pm.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        });
        const responseJson = res.json();
        console.log(responseJson.length);
        pm.environment.set("ItemCount", responseJson.length);
    }
});


Tests tab
const responseJson = pm.response.json();

let CurrentPage = responseJson.current_page;
console.log("current_page:" + CurrentPage);


Result
Getting counts from
https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals

At Pre-request Script, to save 50 into ItemCount environment variable.
Before the main request GET call.
https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1



